# Excluding results from synapse

Tags: search, privacy, locate, synapse

Synapse is showing all results from zeitgeist, locate, ...

How do I exclude some private Results from being displayed in synapse?
Keep files from showing up?

The best would be an option to enter wildcards like "*log" that shouldnt be displayed in the search results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Zeitgeist, it is possible to blacklist some folders in the activity log manager:

[image]

see: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/keep-files-from-showing-up-in-unity.html